# Remove assignments to parameters in Java. What about String type parameters?

Tags: java

Я слышал о правиле «не изменяйте значение параметров» (Not assign to parameters). Но что насчёт строковых параметров?

Например, пусть у меня есть такой метод:

```
public String method(String param) {
    if (param != null) {
        param = do_smth(param); 
    }
    return param;
}
```

Согласно упомянутому правилу, я должен написать нечто такое:

```
public String method(String param) {
    String param_ch = param;
    if (propertyName != null) {
        param_ch = do_smth(param);  
    }
    return param_ch;
}
```

Но что насчёт пула строк? В любом случае как `param`, так и `param_ch` ссылаются на один и тот же объект-строку. То есть разницы между методами фактически нет.

Может быть, правильным решением должно быть такое?

```
public String method(String param) {
    String param_ch = new String(param);
    if (propertyName != null) {
        param_ch = do_smth(param);  
    }
    return param_ch;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Для начала, «не меняйте значений параметров» — это не правило, это рекомендация. Вы можете её нарушать, тогда вам просто придётся держать в голове больше при написании методов.

Проблема с вашей функцией-примером состоит в том, что в ней переменные имеют имена наподобие `param`. То есть, не несут никакой *семантики*, никакого смысла. Если бы вы назвали переменные правильно, то ваш `param` имел бы семантику входного параметра, а `param_ch` — выходного. *Одинаковую* семантику эти две вещи не могут иметь, т. к. они не всегда равны. Поэтому и одинаковое название они тоже не должны иметь.

Давайте напишем пример, когда у нас есть нетривиальная семантика:

```
public String compose_name(String given_name) {
    String full_name = given_name;
    if (surname != null) {
        full_name = add_surname(given_name);  
    }
    return full_name;
}
```

То, что строковые переменные при присвоении ссылки будут фактически ссылаться на тот же объект, не исключение для строк: для любого объекта присвоение ссылок работает так. Но вы должны руководствоваться не этим, а семантикой.